# How to deploy TensorFlow model as a REST service

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on a classification model based on the [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification), everything is working great, now I want to deploy this model as a REST service so that my applications can easily consume it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from the official instruction, [Deployed the trained model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple). Also here is a nice instruction step by step, check this out. [Deploy Tensorflow Model To Production - Part 3 (Creating REST API)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GXBlSnWan4). And blog post on this. [Creating REST API for TensorFlow models](https://becominghuman.ai/creating-restful-api-to-tensorflow-models-c5c57b692c10)